# Mongodb add superuser

Tags: mongodb

I tried adding a 'root' superuser in admin but he can't do anything.

```
> show users
{
    "_id" : "admin.superuser",
    "user" : "superuser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to create admins, users databases, remove, add, edit etc. everything. I know this is not recommended but I'm prototyping, this is not production.

Comment: That looks like a valid root user. What can't the user do? Can you show us an example of something you're trying to do that the user isn't authorized for? Can you show how you created the user? What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @wdberkely I was confused about how mongodb works. One user for the server, one user for root, one user for read write. I thought root was also the user to the server. I realize the hierarchy now!